# Validation Exception with renderx property of table-omit-initial-header using XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, render, xslt-2.0, apache-fop

I am running into an issue when I am creating an XSLT to create PDFs from our XML data. I only want the table headers to repeat after the page break of the table.  When I run it through using the FOP library included with my installation of oXygen 19, I'm receiving:

```
org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: Invalid property encountered on "fo:table": rx:table-omit-initial-header
```

My namespace declarations look like (note: using XSLT 2.0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" 
    xmlns:rx="http://www.renderx.com/XSL/Extensions"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:local-fn="http://www.myfunctions.com/local-fn">
```

the line receiving the error:

```
<fo:table width="100%" rx:table-omit-initial-header="true">
    <fo:table-column column-width="15%"/>
    <fo:table-column column-width="15%"/>
    <fo:table-column column-width="70%"/>
```

Any ideas on why this property is not accepted?

Answer (score 1):

The renderx extensions only work with the [RenderX FO processor](http://www.renderx.com/) (XEP).

Apache FOP doesn't know what to do with `rx:table-omit-initial-header`.

You'll need to setup an XEP transformation scenario in oXygen.

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize that it was an extension that had to be added.  I will look into getting it added to our developer tools.